# How to get the hidden field value in each table row

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

[image]

> i just want to get the hidden field value in each row of the table,how
>   can i do this,any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ApplyProcessingColor()
    {
        $("#xhtml_grid tr").each(function()
        {
            var hdnLock=$(this).find("td:first").text();
            if(hdnLock=='True')
            {
                $(this).css('background-Color','#7FFFD4');
            }
        });
    }
```

in this way i found solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example using arrays. You just want to get the hidden input value and push it to the array.

```js
//create hidden fields array
var hiddenFields = [];

//for each table row
$("#yourTable tr").each(function()
{
  //get hidden field value
  var hiddenField = $(this).find("input[type='hidden']").val();
  
  //if not empty push to array
  if(hiddenField !='undefined'&& hiddenField !=null )
    hiddenFields.push(hiddenField);
});

//output all hidden field values stored in array
console.log(hiddenFields);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="yourTable">
  <tr><th>row id</th><th>column 1</th><th>column 2</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="row id 1"> 1
</td><td>row 1</td><td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="row id 2"> 2
</td><td>row 2</td><td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="row id 3"> 3
</td><td>row 3</td><td>row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks yoda i found a way by looking at your answer.!